# Eclipse RCP: Change target of an action to another item

Tags: eclipse, menu, rcp, cnf

I've got a tree in a view builded with Common Navigation Framework. I've got a custom item MyTreeEntry that contains an IFolder object.

```
public class MyTreeEntry implements IWorkbenchAdapter {
   private IFolder iFolder;
[...]
}
```

I want to see for MyTreeEntry item all menu entries as IFolder (New, Open in new window...) and when an action is invoked, it must act on IFolder contained.

Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using the platform adapter manager to tell Eclipse how to get a folder from your object:

Create an `IAdapterFactory` for your class:

```java
class MyTreeEntryAdapterFactory implements IAdapterFactory
{
  @Override
  public Object getAdapter(Object adaptableObject, Class adapterType)
  {
    if (!(adaptableObject instanceof MyTreeEntry))
      return null;

    if (adapterType == IResource.class || adapterType == IFolder.class)
      return ((MyTreeEntry)adaptableObject).getFolder();

    return null;
  }

  public Class<?> [] getAdapterList()
  {
    return new Class<?> [] {IResource.class, IFolder.class};
  }
}
```

register your adapter factory with the adapter manager:

```java
Platform.getAdapterManager().registerAdapters(adapterFactory, MyTreeEntry.class);
```

You probably need the adapters for `IResource` as well as `IFolder`.

Note: The `IAdaptable` interface provides very similar support but the Eclipse menu system requires the `IAdapterFactory`.

Comment: This is good trick. I've tryed it but the only menu that adds is "Properties". New, Go into, Refresh... aren't visible yet.

Comment: Exactly which menu items show up depends on how they are declared. Some are only declared for a specific view and for those you will have to add your own declaration and some code to your view.

Comment: You might want to look at the source of the Project Explorer in the `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources` plugin which is based on Common Navigator and has the menus you want.

Comment: You're right, but my view extends PackageExplorerPart and has those menus. If I try to right click on Project or Folder I'll see all Eclipse standard menus. If I try to right click on MyTreeEntry I see only Cut, Paste, Import, Export, Show In, Delete, Build Path and, with your code, Properties.

Comment: PackageExplorerPart is in an **internal** package and as such [should not be extended](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) You are going to have to look at the source to see what it expects.

Comment: This is not my code, I know it is a very bad practice to use internal object. But I have to do this issue on this code, even though is bad.